# MS Access Form - unbound textbox causing new record

Tags: ms-access

So I have a bound form.

User updates an unbound combo box, then vba {after_update} populates the value of a bound textbox (1).

I also have an unbound textbox (2).
I can enter text in the unbound text and manually change the value as many times as I want.
However, if (1) is already populated, then any change to the unbound text (2), causes a new record in the underlying table.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting a new record in this context ?
It is 'un'bound, so not sure why it has any effect of the underlying record ?
I just want the user to enter text without any update/commit to the underlying record.

Any guidance appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: My guess: your events (event procedures) are doing different things than you expect. Try setting breakpoints everywhere. -- Without more details (form screenshot, full code) I doubt this can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code into the form's current event, i.e

```
  Private Sub Form_Current()
   #place a copy of all the codes in the after update event in here#
  End Sub
```